# SQL Loop - Add 1 to each batch

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops

Hello I have a file that has batch headers and detail records.  I would like to add a new column that will assign a number to the batch header and then take that number and add it to the detail records.

The data in the first column looks like this.

AAA

BBB

BBB

BBB

BBB

BBB

BBB

AAA

BBB

BBB

BBB

AAA

what i want it to do is this:
The data looks like this

AAA   -   1

BBB   -   1

BBB   -   1

BBB   -   1

BBB   -   1

BBB   -   1

BBB   -   1

AAA   -   2

BBB   -   2

BBB   -   2

BBB   -   2

AAA   -   3

Comment: You mention a file.  Is this (the data) a text file that you want to import?  Or database table that you already have?

Comment: It is a text file that I have imported to a table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is a text or CSV file that you want to import to SQL Server 2008:

- If you need to do this once, I'd fiddle with the file in Excel before
  importing it.
- If you need to do this on a regular basis, I'd write a
  quick console app in .NET to do this for me.  You could then have the app do the push to SQL Server as well to make it a one step process.

If the data is already in SQL Server 2008, I'd still consider doing this in .NET on a record-by-record basis.  .NET is simply a better tool for doing sequential processing than T-SQL is.

If T-SQL is the only tool you have ... it might be possible (using ROW_NUMBER()) to write a couple of batch updates that could do this for you.  But they'd be tricky to get right.  You might have to just use a cursor and attempt sequential processing.

ETA:  If you have SSIS available, you could write a Script Transform to do this for you.  That might actually be the best solution.

Comment: I currently do it in excel, but it is slow and tedious I will look at this .net tool. Thanks